# Proof that mesh current representation exists for a planar circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

A colleague recently introduced me to the idea of [mesh analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis). This is a technique that only works for analyzing planar circuits (i.e., a circuit that is topologically a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)). A planar circuit has "essential meshes," which are the smallest loops that appear in a particular planar representation, and one can assign a "mesh current" to each essential mesh. The mesh current is a hypothetical current that flows around the mesh with a certain orientation. The actual current in a component is the sum or difference of the two mesh currents flowing through it.

It seems obvious that any set of mesh currents will result in a set of actual currents in the components satisfying Kirchoff's junction rule. The junction rule just expresses conservation of charge, and clearly the closed-loop pattern of the mesh currents does conserve charge.

(1) How do we know that the converse is true? That is, how do we know that any set of actual currents satisfying the junction rule can be represented by a set of mesh currents? This seems to have the same flavor as Green's theorem...?

(2) What are the exact conditions for the validity of this type of analysis? Clearly we need a planar circuit. Does it work for any combination of voltage sources, current sources, and other circuit elements for which the junction rule holds? Does it matter if the loop rule fails to hold? Does it matter if the lumped circuit approximation fails?

Comment: I think the book by [Bamberg and Sternberg](https://www.amazon.com/Course-Mathematics-Students-Physics-Bk/dp/0521332451/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1521153513&sr=8-1&keywords=bamberg+and+sternberg) does this, in fact making the connection to Green's/Stokes' theorem, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I think there is a pretty good plausibility argument based on counting degrees of freedom. Consider the circuit as a planar graph with V vertices, E edges, and F faces. By Euler's formula, V-E+F=1. If we count degrees of freedom based on currents through the circuit elements, then we have E currents constrained by V-1 independent junction rules, for E-V+1 degrees of freedom. In the representation with mesh currents, we have F independent mesh currents, for F degrees of freedom. But by Euler's formula the number of degrees of freedom are equal.

Comment: This sounds like the essence of the presentation of Bamberg and Sternberg, but they do it the language of topology and homotopy.  I'm going by a distant memory, here.

Comment: Relevant paper: Feldmann and Rohrer, "Proof of the number of independent Kirchhoff equations in an electrical circuit," IEEE transactions on circuits and systems 38 (1991) 681.